# How do you replace a line of text in a text file (python)

Tags: python, file, text, replace, line

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
unknown value 1
unknown value 2
unknown value 3
unknown value 4
unknown value 5
```

How can I choose a line and replace its contents with another string?

For example:

Change `unknown value 1` to `unknown value 0`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 13):

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('inFile.txt', inplace=True): 
      print line.rstrip().replace('oldLine', 'newLine'),
```

This replaces all lines with the text `'oldLine'`, if you want to replace only the first one then you need to add a condition and break out of the loop.

Adding rstrip() avoids adding an extra space after each line

Comment: You are potentially modifying multiple lines instead of a single selected one.

Comment: You are right, I added a note.

Comment: This adds a new, blank line between each line (even if there is no match)

Comment: I am interested for the solution of the condition and break loop here if possible. If you can add it to the solution I will really appreciate!

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
with open('file', 'r') as input_file, open('new_file', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if line.strip() == 'to replace':
            output_file.write('new line\n')
        else:
            output_file.write(line)
```