# How to update a CSV value

Tags: python, csv

So here's the scenario:

- I have a csv column that stores users points
- I am able to alter the user's 'points
- After changing them, I would like to replace the old score with the new altered one

How can I update this value?

Comment: It looks like you want SO to write code for you. Please show what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I have tried to rewrite the CSV row, with the updated 'score' value already replaced. [User,Password,Score]. However this rewites on a new row, I just wanted it to replace the old equivalent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you replace a line of text in a text file (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622754/how-do-you-replace-a-line-of-text-in-a-text-file-python)

Comment: @sKwa that is the wrong file type

Comment: What method do you use for adding the new line? Please show your code. You tagged python, so it is safe to assume you have used a python script. Show that. I.e. try to get close to a [mcve]. You might also benefit from taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: If you can edit one kind of text file (using sKwa nice link) what keeps you  from doing it on a different kind?

Comment: You need to add the code you have worked so far in your question. That way, we can help you by finding mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make pandas data frame which takes 5 row's and 2 columns as input for example:-

```
import pandas as pd  
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=('col1', 'col2'))  
for i in range(5):  
    res_list = list(map(int, input().split()))  
    res = res.append(pd.Series(res_list,index=['col1','col2']), ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('example.csv', index=False,, header=False)
```

`index` and `header` values are according to your choice